# easySlider doesn't work in IE7

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I tried using easyslider 1.7 in a site and I noticed that in IE7 does not work properly, it shows all the images and the slider does not work.
in all other higher versions of IE and other major browsers everything works perfectly.
The version IE6 does not consider it either.

the URL is:

```
http://www.esteticasilvia.it/php/chisiamo.php
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a well known bug. Have you tried this?

http://clicknathan.com/2011/04/04/easy-slider-1-7-with-internet-explorer-7-bug-fix/